# Ruby (Rack) App could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new to coding and setting up servers, etc.

I received the below on my site and didn't change any code and am having no problems on my hosting site, but my site isn't loading.  What could be the reason, and how can I fix this?

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
These are the possible causes:
There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass
Exception class:
NoMethodError
Application root:
/home/ubuntu/nteeq/current
Backtrace:
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home/ubuntu/nteeq/releases/20120430040248/config/initializers/exception_notification.rb    6   
1   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    235 in `load'
2   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    235 in `load'
3   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    227 in `load_dependency'
4   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    235 in `load'
5   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb    201 
6   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb    200 in `each'
7   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb    200 
8   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb 25  in `instance_exec'
9   /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb 25  in `run'
10  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb 50  in `run_initializers'
11  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb 49  in `each'
12  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb 49  in `run_initializers'
13  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb   134 in `initialize!'
14  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb   77  in `send'
15  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb   77  in `method_missing'
16  /home/ubuntu/nteeq/releases/20120430040248/config/environment.rb    5   
17  config.ru   3   in `require'
18  config.ru   3   
19  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb    46  in `instance_eval'
20  /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb    46  in `initialize'
21  config.ru   1   in `new'
22  config.ru   1   
Powered by Phusion Passenger, mod_rails / mod_rack for Apache.
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is in `config/initializers/exception_notification.rb`. Post the contents of that file so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have all the gems you need

```
bundle install
```

If you get permission problems try

```
sudo bundle install
```

(in the directory of your rails app). This will install all the necessary gems and dependencies for your rails app.

Comment: Updating the rails gem manually is unnecessary and won't change the app's behavior if using bundler.

Comment: It looks like he's missing core gems though?

Comment: It doesn't matter, bundler will install the correct rails gem. As long as bundler is installed, running `bundle install` is sufficient to ensure all gems are installed.

Comment: Using `sudo` for bundle installs is likely to cause problems down the line. It should not be necessary, and if it is, there's something else wrong with the environment.